# Geth Sync Problems | Rinkeby, Ropsten | Deploy contracts

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, contract-deployment

Get Geth to sync --> Rinkeby test network. For the love of god I just want to deploy a contract. I have deployed it to Ganache-cli, GUI, remixIDE, deployed with truffle/Infuria.io...I keep failing to synchronize the rinkeby network. I have tried on macOS with commands `geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net" --ipcpath "~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc"`

I tried on windows, ubuntu and I had the same problem.

I will fire up `geth attach` and  eth.syncing will show the blocks climbing and there will be maybe around 100 blocks left and then it will show an error: Synchronization failed, dropped peers etc etc. The eth blocknumber, eth latest block shows zero, wallet shows zero balance even though I transferred test eth to the account and it shows up on Ropsten/Rinkeny Etherescans.

- I have tried no ipcpath declaration
- Deleting the blockchain data and restarting
- Checking the time sync
- I have tried ropsten network syncing same problem
- I have heard you cannot sync with a standard HDD? I don't know, is this true for test networks? Mainnet?

I am sure I am doing something wrong on my end because I have tried multiple OSs, different systems. Please any assistance would greatly be appreciated. Too many hours, my chest hurts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!
Unfortunately this appears to be an existing error with Ethereum, especially the rinkeby network. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14381
My recommendation would be to try restarting the node a few more times while tracking dev progress.

Answer (score 0):

I can sync `rinkeby` without any problems using the following command:

```
geth --rinkeby --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --allow-insecure-unlock
```